# HelpHelp to debug my React Code

Tags: reactjs, jsx

First of all, I want to ask whether is my statement is correct :
"When we are making components, it is better to put it in different files"
Is it correct? since currently I tried so, and it cause problems.

Parents :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {SubmitComponent} from './submitComponent.jsx';
import {topicTable} from './topicTable.jsx';
// import {TopicsContainer} from './TopicsContainer.js'

const dashboardStyle = {
  border: '2px solid black',
  width: '70%',
  height: 'auto',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  marginRight: 'auto',
  marginBottom: '100px',
};


class AppDashBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datas: []
    }
  }

  submitTopic = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.state.datas);
    console.log(this.state.datas.concat([data]));
    this.setState({
      datas: this.state.datas.concat(data)
    });
    console.log(this.state.datas);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={dashboardStyle}>
        <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Coding Exercise</h1>
        <hr /> 
        <SubmitComponent submitTopic={this.submitTopic} />
        <topicTable topics={this.state.datas} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AppDashBoard
```

and this is the topicTable component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {oneTopic} from './oneTopic.jsx';

export class topicTable extends Component {
    render() {
        const topicstable = this.props.topics.map((topic) => (
            <oneTopic
                title={topic.title}
                desc = {topic.desc}
                vote = {topic.vote}
            />
        ));
        console.log("HAHAHAHA");
        return (
            <div id="topics">
                {oneTopic}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and Lastly, my oneTopic component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class oneTopic extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{width:'96%', height:300, backgroundColor :'#AAA'}}>
                <h1>HAHAHAHA</h1>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

My problems are :
1) In the topicTable component, the console.log("HAHAHA") is not executed at all, I wonder why ?
2) Also for the oneTopic, the

HAHAHA

is not showing at all.

Even I already export and import everything

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters.

1) rename oneTopic to OneTopic

2) change {oneTopic} to `<oneTopic />`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!
Which means, a component cannot start with lowercase huh